# Are red-heads going extinct?

Tags: evolution, genetics, hair

There is a widely-held belief that there will no longer be humans with red hair in the future (sometimes cited by 2060 or 2100).

For example, these Facebook groups:

- ["Save the ginger kids, there going extinct D:"](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Save-the-ginger-kids-there-going-extinct-D/396533380532)

  > One of my teachers told me that in a couple years there wont be any ginger kids left
- ["Jump on a Ginger"](https://www.facebook.com/JumpOnAGinger/info?tab=page_info)

  > Currently, two percent of the world’s population is adorned with red hair. Scientists have speculated that this rare breed may possibly going extinct.
- [Ginger Moses](https://www.facebook.com/GingerMoses/posts/131601410298639)

  > They say that 2060 will be the end of the road for Gingers

The justifications given include:

- red hair is a recessive gene ([Seattle Times](http://www.seattletimes.com/life/lifestyle/will-rare-redheads-be-extinct-by-2100/)):

  > If predictions by the Oxford Hair Foundation come to pass, the number of natural redheads everywhere will continue to dwindle until there are none left by the year 2100.
  >
  > The reason, according to scientists at the independent institute in England, which studies all sorts of hair problems, is that just 4 percent of the world’s population carries the red-hair gene. The gene is recessive and therefore diluted when carriers produce children with people who have the dominant brown-hair gene.
- climate change ([The Week](http://theweek.com/speedreads/450390/redheads-could-become-extinct-thanks-climate-change)):

  > Only 1 to 2 percent of people in the world have red hair — and that number could continue to decrease due to climate change, scientists warn.

Is this just a myth, or will ginger hair soon cease to be?

Comment: I removed the claim that the extinction was due to "genetic admixture", because I couldn't find anyone claiming it. I put other justifications I did find into the question. Note: I had to cherry pick my search results, because most of the results were debunking the claim. Does the Internet really need this question asked again?

Comment: Isn't the statement 'the gene is recessive and therefore diluted' debunked by even the most basic knowledge on how inheritance works? Unless it has impact on the ability to reproduce, a recessive trait is passed on to children with the same probability as a dominant trait .

Comment: If 4 percent of the world’s population carries the red-hair gene, then even in the unlikely event that all of these were single recessive cases (so there were no red haired people in a particular generation) then 2 percent of the relevant alleles would be red-hair genes and with random mixing 0.02*0.02*7 billion i.e. 2.8 million of the next generation would show red hair.   But if 2 percent of the world currently actually has red hair despite it being a recessive gene, then 4 percent of the world carrying the gene looks like an underestimate

Comment: @Oddthinking Thanks for fixing the question! You would have found many more claims if you typed `site:facebook.com` along with your search terms though!

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: It is basic knowledge, so, an answer should be easy.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: Uh, that would *restrict* the number of claims I found. But, more to the point: If you want to mention "genetic admixture", great - find a notable source.

Comment: @Oddthinking Sorry, I forgot the smiley face after that sentence to show non-seriousness. And I don't have a source for that, because not *everybody* posts rumours on Facebook. If "I heard it from somebody" was a notable source, then I've got quite a few. :-)

Comment: @Oddthinking, sometimes a claim is too basic to be easily debunked: it's very easy to find explanations of *why* the sky is blue, but much harder to find support for the statement that it *is* blue.

Comment: From Brit Lab: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDMEIrkt7Po

Answer (score 2):

Some phenotypes caused by recessive genes occur in sub-populations that tend to reproduce with other members of the sub-population.

For example, [Tay-Sachs disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tay%E2%80%93Sachs_disease) is a recessive genetic disease caused by having two bad alleles of a gene, and mainly occurs in specific sub-populations who reproduce with each other:

> Tay–Sachs disease (also known as GM2 gangliosidosis or hexosaminidase A deficiency) is a rare autosomal recessive genetic disorder.
>
> ...
>
> who described in 1887 the cellular changes of Tay–Sachs disease and noted an increased disease prevalence in Ashkenazi Jewish people.
>
> Research in the late 20th century demonstrated that Tay–Sachs disease is caused by a genetic mutation in the HEXA gene on (human) chromosome 15. A large number of HEXA mutations have been discovered, and new ones are still being reported. These mutations reach significant frequencies in specific populations. French Canadians of southeastern Quebec have a carrier frequency similar to that seen in Ashkenazi Jews, but carry a different mutation. Cajuns of southern Louisiana carry the same mutation that is seen most commonly in Ashkenazi Jews. HEXA mutations are rare and are most seen in genetically isolated populations. Tay–Sachs can occur from the inheritance of either two similar, or two unrelated, causative mutations in the HEXA gene.

If individuals with the alleles for red hair continue reproducing at the same rate that others are, then the frequency of the red-hair allele will remain the same.

However, if populations with a high frequency of the red-hair allele decide to stop reproducing predominantly with other members of the same sub-population, then it's possible that the overall frequency of the red hair phenotype may decrease, as the number of individuals homozygous for the red hair allele will decrease, and the number of individuals heterozygous for the allele will increase.

The section [Deviations from Hardy–Weinberg equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Weinberg_principle#Deviations_from_Hardy.E2.80.93Weinberg_equilibrium) in the Wikipedia article on the Hardy–Weinberg principle also states that non-random mating, also known as inbreeding, causes an increase in homozygosity.

Interracial marriage is becoming more socially acceptable in the United States ([XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1431/)), and is becoming more common ([blog post citing Pew Center research](http://www.blogher.com/latest-statistics-divorce-rates-among-interracial-marriages)). If the same trend is happening in Scotland and Ireland, which have a high proportion of redheads ([do I really need a citation?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_hair#North_and_West_Europe)), then this will lead to a decrease in the number of individuals homozygous for the red head allele, and therefore fewer redheads.

Comment: I *was* planning to self-answer this question, but seeing this I'm glad I didn't: +1 for the sheer effort.

Comment: You explain very well *how* their numbers might be changing. The question is if they actually are. Will there be less red heads in the future?

Comment: I don't think a predictive answer is possible. Data on breeding habits of high red-haired populations is likely difficult to find, if not impossible. The answer does provide a plausible mechanism for how it could happen, and demonstrates that the current social situation seems to provide opportunity for that mechanism.

Comment: @fredsbend Under the premise that the existence of the allele is not decreasing in numbers (nothing is selecting _against_ red-haired people/carriers), it is not, as a trait, going extinct. We may by chance _see_ less red-heads if they have more kids with people who have dominating alleles, but they will still be present and can pop up. Hypothetically, the allele (expressed or unexpressed) could be growing in the overall population, and we could see an increase of them later when they're more populous in a broader group.

Comment: I agree with @fredsbend, this answer gives a nice introduction to the genetics around this question, but doesn't answer it. If redheads marry with non-redheads, then their offspring will unlikely be red headed. However, do they? I thought this was the whole point of the question -- not "is the red head gene recessive?" but "is this recessive gene disappearing?"

Comment: @HarrisWeinstein Do you have any backup for your claim that 'nothing is selecting against red-haired people/carriers'? I am not saying that there necessarily is, but I find it highly likely that social or cultural preference could easily cause a skew for/against a visually obvious trait, even if there is no direct biological reason.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo While I think you're somewhat asking me to prove a negative, I was able to find this paper on Springer saying that while general preferences for or against red hair isn't non-existent, it is generally limited. Past that, I think it's safe to say (barring positive evidence) nothing is actively killing red-hair carriers significantly more than anyone else.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Accidentally removed link to article- [here it is](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs40750-014-0008-y)